# Changing div position to fixed with javascript attaches the div to document not viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a way to determine if any part of a div is touching the top of the viewport and fix an item in that div to the top of the viewport using vanilla javascript.

I have been able to sort out how to determine if the div is touching the top of the viewport and trigger changes to the div's style.  But for some reason when I change the div's `position: absolute` to `position: fixed` the div fixes to the top of the document, not to the top of the viewport, hence is not visible.

My js

```
function touchTop() {
  var div = $('itin');
  var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
  var y = rect.top;
  var h = rect.bottom;
  if ((y < 0) && (h > 0)) {
    document.getElementById('seemore').style.position = 'fixed';
    document.getElementById('seemore').style.top = '45%';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('seemore').style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById('seemore').style.top = '66px';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', touchTop);
```

The basic div HTML

```
<div id="itin" class="container">
  <div class="sp20"></div>
  <div class="text rgt">
    <h3>your daily adventures</h3>
    <p>blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
  <div id="seemore" class="ghstbtn">See More</div>
</div>
```

And the basic initial CSS

```
#seemore {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

**To clarify further:** My problem that needs solving is that when javascript changes the style.position to fixed the #seemore div gets positioned such that the 'top' value is measured from the top of the document, not from the top of the viewport.  So basically not visible in the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think your problem lays here:

```
if ((y < 0) && (h > 0))
```

When the container div hits the top of the document, position to "seemore" is set to fixed, but as fast as the bottom of the div hits the top of the document, 
"h === 0" and the position is again set to absolute.

Try this.

```
const seeMore = document.getElementById('seemore');
const div = document.getElementById('itin');

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkBoundries);

function checkBoundries() {
    var rect = div.getBoundingClientRect();
    var y = rect.top;
    var h = rect.bottom;
    if (y < 0) {
        seeMore.style.position = 'fixed';
        seeMore.style.top = '45%';
    } else {
        seeMore.style.position = 'absolute';
        seeMore.style.top = '66px';
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually want the div to revert to absolute once the div scrolls out of view.  But my real issue is that the fixed div ends up attached to the document not the viewport.

Comment: @Tom Thats, that's odd. For me it stays 45% down from the top of the viewport when i scroll..

Comment: Not sure if it effects something, but the entire document is quite long and the #itin div is but a small part.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be related to a filter applied to a parent of a parent of a parent of a ....

Found some old questions regarding issues with transformations and position:fixed dating back some 5 to 7 years ago.  And even though many mentioned filing issue reports with the browser makers, it seems the problem has never been addressed and resolved.  One comment mentioned filters could also cause the issue.

Moved the filter to a separate class which is now added and removed, rather than applying the filter directly to the div.  And everything works as expected.